# Splitting a list of values in a Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

I was working with the Gun violence dataset from Kaggle which had the age column like this:

```
In [5]: df['participant_age_group'].head()
Out [5]: 
0    0::Adult 18+||1::Adult 18+||2::Adult 18+||3::A...
1    0::Adult 18+||1::Adult 18+||2::Adult 18+||3::A...
2    0::Adult 18+||1::Adult 18+||2::Adult 18+||3::A...
3    0::Adult 18+||1::Adult 18+||2::Adult 18+||3::A...
4    0::Adult 18+||1::Adult 18+||2::Teen 12-17||3::...
Name: participant_age_group, dtype: object
```

Where `0::`,`1::` correspond to index. So I want to split them and forma a whole new dataframe with no. of people belonging to that age group and having total no. of people belonging to that age group, say `df_age`. For ex:

```
Age Group  No_of_people

18         300
25         210
30         100
```

So that I can then `.groupby(age)` and `No_of_people.value_counts()` by `No._of_people` and visualize the age group which is responsible for max. gun violences.
Unfortunately I'm only able to split but then not coming up to what I want.

Comment: And how did you approach this problem? Maybe you are close and people can correct a minor mistake in your code instead of providing a new one from scratch? Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I started from this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'participant_age_group':['0::Adult 18+||1::Adult 18+||2::Adult 18+||',
                                            '0::Adult 18+||1::Adult 18+||2::Adult 18+||',
                                            '0::Adult 25+||1::Adult 25+||2::Adult 30+||',
                                          '0::Adult 18+||1::Adult 18+||2::Teen 12-17||']})
```

then to create the `df_age`:

```
df_age = (df['participant_age_group'].str.replace('+','')
                                     .str.split('\|{2}',expand=True).stack()
                                     .str.split(' ',expand=True).dropna()
                                     .groupby(1,as_index=False).count()
                                     .rename(columns={0:'No_of_people',1:'Age_group'}))
```

Some explanation of the code.

`str.split('\|{2}',expand=True).stack()` splits each row where the symbol `||` is in the `string` and stack will expand as a column instead in the row. You get something like this, where the first level of index is your rows number in your original `df`.

```
0  0      0::Adult 18
   1      1::Adult 18
   2      2::Adult 18
   3                 
1  0      0::Adult 18
   1      1::Adult 18
...
```

(I don't print all the data). Then `str.split(' ',expand=True).dropna()` will split each string were a space is (before the age) and also drop empty rows to get:

```
            0      1
0 0  0::Adult     18
  1  1::Adult     18
  2  2::Adult     18
1 0  0::Adult     18
  1  1::Adult     18
...
```

Here you can see you have created two columns, 0 and 1, and in the column 1 you have the ages, so you just have to groupby this column and count the occurence of each age with `groupby(1,as_index=False).count()`

With my input, `df_age` is like:

```
  Age_group  No_of_people
0     12-17             1
1        18             8
2        25             2
3        30             1
```

Comment: hey can you please explain from this step: `.str.split('\|{2}',expand=True).stack()`
                                                                    `.str.split(' ',expand=True).dropna()`
                                                                    `.groupby(1,as_index=False).count()`

Comment: @DebadriDutta I added some explanations, hope it's more clear